# What is the type of a multidim array in shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, shared-ptr

I have some problem with type casting.
Here is working code:

```
void init(signed char[16][16][16])
{
}

int main()
{
    auto cache = new signed char[16][16][16];
    init(cache);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is a code with a problem if compiled in Windows. In Linux this code works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<signed char[16][16][16]> ptr;
    ptr.reset(new signed char[16][16][16]);
    init(ptr.get());
    return 0;
}
```

MSVS gives me an error: Error   C2664   'void init(signed char [][16][16])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'signed char (*)[16][16][16]' to 'signed char [][16][16]'

How to correctly use multidim arrays with shared_ptr? What is the type name of "auto cache"?

Comment: what about using std::array<> ?

Comment: Your code compiles for me on VS2019, what version are you using?

Comment: @john msvs 2015

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` for arrays is available from C++17 and above, no? VS 2015 does not support that AFAIK. `std::array` is the way to go.

Comment: @DeiDei wow, I didn't know about support. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with 3D `shared_ptr`

```
using myType = signed char;
using ManagedInt = std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<myType>>> ;

const int N = 16;

{
    auto managedMat = ManagedInt();
    managedMat.reset(new std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<myType>>[N], [](auto p) {
           for(uint32_t i = 0; i <N; ++i){
                p->reset();
           }
        });
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i< N;++i){
        managedMat.get()[i].reset(new std::shared_ptr<myType>[N], [](auto p) {
           for(uint32_t i = 0; i <N; ++i){
                p->reset();
           }
        });
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < N; ++j){
            managedMat.get()[i].get()[j].reset(new myType[N], [](auto p) {
                delete[] p;
        });
        }
    }
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            for(uint32_t k = 0; k < N; ++k)
                managedMat.get()[i].get()[j].get()[k] = j;


    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            for(uint32_t k = 0; k < N; ++k)
                std::cout<<managedMat.get()[i].get()[j].get()[k];       
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/Poest-)

I recommend using vector though if you can

Comment: Thanks! I changed std::shared_ptr to boost::shared_ptr(I use boost in my project) and it worked for me.